Examples of dramatic political conversions
I was recently reading about Joram van Klaveren, one time MP and member of the Dutch far right, Islamophobic Party For Freedom lead by Geert Wilders. He was well known for his anti-Islamic rhetoric and started writing a polemical anti-Islamic work. Then, suddenly and unexpectedly, in the course of writing his book, at the age of 40, he had a change of heart and converted to Islam. As described in his own words:

“It sounds a little bit like a fairytale, but it really happened,” he
said.
His heaving bookshelf collapsed, he said, its contents tumbling to the
floor. As he picked up a copy of the Qur’an that had fallen, he said
he glanced at where his finger had landed. “It said in the
translation: ‘It’s not the eyes that are blind, but the hearts,’” he
said.
“And I thought: ‘Well, yeah, this is really my problem.’”

The conversion came as a shock to his own former colleagues, with Wilders describing it like a "vegetarian going to work in a slaughterhouse".
I found the story intrigueing and am now wondering whether we have other, similarly dramatic, cases of conversion? Not necessarily involving religion. Say from far right to far left? From anti-green policies to an environmental campaigner, or the opposite. From anarchist to globalist?

A known case in Germany is Horst Mahler, who went from being far left (member of the far left terror organisation RAF and earlier as a lawyer defender of left wing student activists) to far right (holocaust denier, member of nationalist extremist right wing NPD and their legal defender).
Now this case may be explained saying that "far left and far right in many aspects are not so far away", and certainly there is a continuity in terms of fundamental opposition against the mainstream system and rather unpleasant views he held on both sides. But still, after WWII, Germany's far left was strongly antifascist, protesting against Nazis supposedly still in charge (and certainly in many cases in office) in the new republic, and to become a holocaust denier from there is quite a change.
That said Mahler never held a political office, so not sure how relevant this is, but I thought I mention him anyway.

I first thought Mahler was a brilliant example as he went from RAF to NPD and took prison sentences for both, indicating a level of conviction and not just opportunism. But reading through Mahler's wikipedia... That dude has always been weird. His father was fanatic Nazi who committed suicide in 1949. He joined far right fraternities, then the social democrats, who expelled him because he was also a member of the SDS (socialists students), then RAF, then Greens, then FDP, then NPD, antisemitism and holocaust denial, Reichsbürger... Probably "extremism" rather than a change of heart.

Or perhaps a member of some spy agency?

Could you give some more details into what you'd count? Like Mussolini went from Marxist to Fascist, the Italian syndicalists movement apparently went from far left to far right. Merkel was famously for nuclear energy and after Fukushima accelerated getting out of nuclear reactors. And googling "oil manager turns environmentalist" you find stuff like that: https://www.aacsb.edu/insights/articles/2022/08/how-an-oil-executive-became-an-environmentalist
Though if you look beneath the surface, Mussolini was kicked out of the socialist party, was into syndicalism more for the radicalized "us vs them" situation rather than their actual cause and might have never understood socialism or Marx to begin with, but just liked the revolutionary antic.
Merkel might have never had the change of heart, that made her realize nuclear reactors are dangerous, more likely she knew that from the beginning but thought the risk was manageable (Chernobyl had already happened...). What changed her mind was probably not so much Fukushima, but that she saw that it meant her party was losing local elections already and so she took a radical turn on her course.
And that article seems to be mostly "greenwashing", presenting a green image for an industry that is nothing but green.
So many "dramatic conversions" might just come from a lack of context and background information, where the actual conversion might have happened over a long period of time or where the presentation of either side was just phony or opportunistic or even when fanatic, coming from misconceptions and more strategically motivated decisions.
Like often enough a change of the theme of ones activism is not the same as a change of one's character. One might have been fervent but superficial follower of X and afterwards an equally fervent and equally superficial follower of the opposite.
Mandela might be a more fitting example, who became radicalized by it's conditions into supporting violence and even rejecting to be released from prison under conditions of giving up the armed fight and when finally released wasn't the terrorist anymore that western leaders had expected. That being said it's questionable whether he was that to begin with and whether these were deeply held believes or rather the reality that non-violent protests didn't work, while decades later things had changed making it viable again.

I’ll go with the Benito Mussolini he went from communist to socialist legislature to founder of the far right fascist party.
Hitler too.  Originally he attended the political demonstrations as an employee informant for the secret police.  He ended up leading the group and a failed coupe declaring himself the leader of the beer hall putsch.  And we all know how he ended up.

In the other direction there is the italian politician https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magdi_Allam .
The most staunch omophobic politicians often have a dramatic political conversion when switching to their private life.
The anarchist/globalist is a false dichotomy:

I would be careful, treating most "dramatic politic conversions" as simply that cosmetic changes to the same mindset (for example, an hypothetical nazist that converts to judaism, only to enforce a violent defence and supremacy of its own religion instead of the so-called aryan race).

"The most staunch [h]omophobic politicians often have a dramatic political conversion when switching to their private life." - that's more an example of hypocrisy than what the question is asking for. "The anarchist/globalist is a false dichotomy" - the cartoon you've posted compares anarchists and libertarians, not anarchists and globalists; libertarianism and globalism are very different political ideologies.

I don't think Magdi Allam is a particularly good example. He appears to have left Islam at a pretty young age if he ever identified with the religion at all.

In any case, it certainly is not an example of a political conversion since he didn't campaign for Islam and then change to campaigning against Islam.

@F1Krazy Yeah "libertarians" aren't libertarian or anarchists and even the wiki article on globalism starts with "Globalism has multiple meanings.". Like if it's the things that Nazis are so afraid about, then anarchists might be all for globalism, seeing oneself as a citizen of the globe rather than being caught up in nationalist bullshit, while if it's about global domination via markets and economic imbalances then you'd have much more opposition to that...

@BenCohen probably more clear is Allam's [2003] conversion from communism-linked causes to the center-right. His religious conversion/baptism was more in that vein, although he did make some hay about proselytizing among Muslims (although it's hard to see how much influence he'd have there--although there are still some nearly communist Palestinian parties etc.)

OTOH, reading the whole wiki piece, he did harden his stance against Islam over time too, from seeing it as ok-ish to not. This answer could probably do more to explain all that instead of the somewhat gratuitous cartoon etc. (OTOH I suppose that's addressing the last suggestion in the Q.)

But the way the OP uses 'globalist', they probably mean a supporter of a [putative] 'world government', rather than globalization through trade etc.

@thegodsfromengineering wouldn't that just be traditional (i.e pre-Stalinist) Marxism? In which case, you're essentially looking at the political history of someone like Bertrand Russell.
